# Terminology for properties of functions.

Tags: functions, terminology

So I was wondering, is there a name for a function whose output is always less than or equal to its input ($f(x)≤x$)? I know there is a name for functions that satisfy $x_1<x_2\rightarrow f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ (monotonic) so I figured there would be a name for $f(x)≤x$. Does anyone know what it is? A good example of this would be the greatest integer function $\lfloor x\rfloor$. Thank you.

Comment: A function satisfying "$x_1<x_2\rightarrow f(x_1)<f(x_2)$" is called *strictly increasing*, not *monotonic*.

Comment: I've seen functions satisfying "$x \le f(x)$" called *inflationary*, *progressive*, or *extensive*. Thus one could use *deflationary* or *regressive* for your property, but I haven't actually seen such usage.

Comment: In mathematics, a monotonic function (or monotone function) is a function that preserves the given order:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function.

Oh and thanks for your comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

*Regressive function* appears to be a common term in set theory: e.g. [Regressive function on an ordinal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44617/79365) and [set of infinite cardinals admits an injective regressive function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5362/79365). It requires strict inequality, but if you use it outside of set theory, you are going to explain the term anyway, which will give you an opportunity to say that only $\leq$ is required.

> In mathematics, a monotonic function (or monotone function) is a function that preserves the given order: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function)

Wikipedia is great, but it is not a holy script. The function $f(x)=-x$ is monotone, although it reverses the order of $\mathbb R$ instead of preserving it.

Comment: A holy script could be great or not, like Wikipedia.